# Compare array over matrix without loop

Tags: r

I need an array Y of integers and NA to compare to a matrix and return TRUE, FALSE, or NA. I'm limited in how I can write this - no loops or if statements. It has to be very plain. The issue is that it only compares the length of the array without repeating over the rest of the matrix; also, it isn't correctly recognizing FALSE values.

I know it's my apply function but I don't know how to get `apply()` to repeat by itself without looping.

```
answer <- function(x,y){
  y <- as.matrix(y)
  z <- apply(apply(x,2,`==`,y),1,any)
  q <- as.matrix(z)
  print(q)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you see the matrix but R is a mostly vectorized language you don't need loops to compare elements of different sizes, but be mindful of direction and of recycling

```
answer <- function(x,y){
  cat('+++++Solution 4+++++\n')
  q <- x == y
  print(q)
}

x <- matrix(c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1), nrow=4, ncol=4)
y <- c(1, 1, 1, NA)

answer(x,y)
```

Or solution by row very ugly stuff

```
answer <- function(x,y){
  cat('+++++Solution 4+++++\n')
  q <- matrix(apply(t(y),1,`==`,t(x)),nrow = 4,byrow = TRUE)
  print(q)
}

answer(x,y)
```

Comment: That was so much easier than the way I was conceptualizing it in my head. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem, if you can accept the answer I would be glad

Comment: Is there a way to ensure it goes row by row instead of column by column?

Comment: I see I made a mistake, sorry about that, trying to see a easy way to make row-wise comparisson

Comment: Yeah please that the solved away, that is actually quite a challenging problem

Comment: Yeah I think I solved it, not pretty but will get the job done